# Jquery .each loop logic

Tags: jquery

Goal:  assign the data-column-* class to the tbody > tr > td element associated with that column.

The th contain the correct classes so the first loop is functioning as expected. 
The second .each() loop I am dumping the entire array.

I tried assigning arr[arr.length -1]

```js
$('.table-color thead').find(function(){ 
 headerRowCount = [];

 $('tr th').each(function(){
  headerRow  = $(this).length;
  headerRowCount.push(headerRow);
  
  $(headerRowCount).each(function(index, value){
   i = index; 
  });

  $(this).addClass("data-column-" + i);
 });
});  


$('.table-color tbody').find(function(){
 rowCount = [];

 $('tr').each(function(){
  row = $(this).length;
  rowCount.push(row);
  console.log(row);
  $(rowCount).each(function(index, value){
   i = index; 
  });
  $('td').addClass("data-column-" + i);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table-color">
  <thead>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>data</td><td>data 2</td><td>data 3</td><td>data 4</td><td>data 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data</td><td>data 2</td><td>data 3</td><td>data 4</td><td>data 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data</td><td>data 2</td><td>data 3</td><td>data 4</td><td>data 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data</td><td>data 2</td><td>data 3</td><td>data 4</td><td>data 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data</td><td>data 2</td><td>data 3</td><td>data 4</td><td>data 5</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('td').addClass("data-column-" + i);
```

When you say this you mean all the td's in the page so eventually it's quite normal that they all have the 5 classes.

I think what you wanted is more something like that :

```
$('tr').each(function(){ // for each <TR>
 $(this).find('td').each(function(index){ // loop through all TDs 
        $(this).addClass("data-column-" + index);// and add the class
    });
});
```

And you can see it in action overthere :
http://jsfiddle.net/LL7q5jje/

Comment: The relevant code from that jsFiddle needs to be included in your answer so that it still has value even if the link no longer works. It's also "you", not "u"; have some pride in your answer and type those extra few characters.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I'll do so

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are searching for `th`'s inside of your `tr`'s, but there are no `th`'s living there in the markup you shared.  If you are trying to get all of the `th`'s inside of `thead`, simply remove the `tr`.

Your markup doesn't follow this pattern:

`$('tr th').each(...`

Also, `.find()` does not accept a function.  You will need to query the element on your own, then pass that element as an argument to `.find()`.

Perhaps save the result of an `$.each()` query to a variable value and pass that to `.find()`.

Comment: [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) doesn't accept a function. This won't work.

Comment: @Stryner Thanks for the heads up.  I was running to a meeting and didn't proof read well enough :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to loop over all tr elements, and then td's in that tr.
I can be done pretty simple:

```
$('.table-color tbody tr').each(function(i, tr){

    $(tr).find("td").each(function(y, td){
        $(td).addClass("data-column-" + y);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dqhxxujt/

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for 2 functions. Since you are already do a loop for all columns in the 1st function, just use [`:nth-child() Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) in the loop for `TR > TD` elements. So you can do all of this with this simple function :

```
$('.table-color thead th').each(function(index){        
   var i = parseInt(index) + 1; 
   $(this).addClass("data-column-" + i);
   $('.table-color tbody tr td:nth-child('+i+')').addClass("data-column-" + i);
});
```

See : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gzua7wes/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to understand, but I think your problem is that classes were being applied to all TD instead of the specific column?

Based on this understanding, I've simplified the code. jQuery's each function has it's own index that you can use so you don't need to generate your own.

```js
$('tr > th').each(function(index){
  var i = parseInt(index)+1;
  $(this).addClass("data-column-" + i);
}); 

$('tr').each(function(){
  $(this).children('td').each(function(index) {
    var i = parseInt(index)+1;
    $(this).addClass("data-column-" + i);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table-color">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>data</td><td>data 2</td><td>data 3</td><td>data 4</td><td>data 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data</td><td>data 2</td><td>data 3</td><td>data 4</td><td>data 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data</td><td>data 2</td><td>data 3</td><td>data 4</td><td>data 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data</td><td>data 2</td><td>data 3</td><td>data 4</td><td>data 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data</td><td>data 2</td><td>data 3</td><td>data 4</td><td>data 5</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```